# Erro: conexão com o banco de dados já aberta

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, postgresql, conexão

Estou criando um método para testar uma conexão com o banco de dados PostgreSQL, porém ao chamar o método que abre a conexão acontece um erro dizendo que a conexão já está aberta e não funciona o 'if' para checagem de status da conexão.

> Exception : "connection already open".

```
public static bool TestaConn()
{
    bool Retorno = false;

    ConexaoBanco = AbreBD();

    if (ConexaoBanco.State == ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        ConexaoBanco.Close();
        Retorno = true;
    }
    return Retorno;
}
```

Método que abre conexão, sendo a string de conexão uma variável global:

```
public static NpgsqlConnection AbreBD()
    {
        try
        {
            if (ConexaoBanco.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
               ConexaoBanco.ConnectionString = ConfGeral.StringConnexaoGeral;
               ConexaoBanco.Open();                    
            }

            return ConexaoBanco;

        }
        catch (Exception erro)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Falha na Tentativa de Acesso a Base de Dados Informada:\n{0}\n \nSE PRECISAR ENTRE EM CONTATO COM NOSSO SUPORTE", erro.Message), "e-SistemIntegra", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            return ConexaoBanco;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Posta o código da classe `ConexaoBanco`, por favor

Comment: ConexaoBanco é apenas uma variável estática do tipo NpgsqlConnection e tanto a variável ConexaoBanco quanto esses métodos estão dentro de uma mesma classe. * public class 
DataBaseAccess
    {
        private static NpgsqlConnection ConexaoBanco = new NpgsqlConnection();

Comment: A resposta que postei não ajudou?

Comment: Não, continua fazendo a mesma verificação.

Comment: Você quer não ter problemas com conexões abertas ou quer verificar se a conexão está aberta?

Comment: As duas coisas, consegui colocar funcionando agora, mas tive que mudar minha variável de conexão para uma variável local em cada método, sendo que antes estava tentando com uma variável global static;

Comment: Entendi. Eu ia sugerir para você colocar o código que recebe o retorno de `AbreBD()` em um bloco `using`, aí, ao sair do bloco a conexão seria encerrada. Você garantiria que sempre que finalizasse o bloco a conexão seria encerrada.

Answer (score 1):

Troque

```
if (ConexaoBanco.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
```

Por

```
if (ConexaoBanco.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
```

---

Documentação do `enum` [ConnectionState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.connectionstate(v=vs.110).aspx).

Reposta baseada [nessa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13544305/connecting-to-postgresql).

Answer (score 0):

Provavelmente o (ConexaoBanco.State == ConnectionState.Closed) não serve para realizar essa operação, se não me engano eu acho que existe um método relacionado a essas classes de conexão que verifica se está aberto a conexão ...
`ConexaoBanco.isOpen()`

Ai seria assim

```
if (ConexaoBanco.isOpen())
{
        ConexaoBanco.Close();
        Retorno = true;
}
```

Algo assim se não me engano.

Comment: ConexaoBanco é uma variável estática e não possui o método de extensão isOpen().